# How do i print a file in my c++ program with words taken out?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program in c++ and I need to ask the user for a file name, print the file and then reprint it with every 5th word missing. I've gotten as far as to asking them file name, checking for errors and printing out the file, I'm just completely lost on how to reprint it with every 5th word missing, any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{   

const int SIZE = 51;

    char fileName[SIZE];

char ch;

ifstream inFile;

bool lastWasLetter = true;

const string UNDERLINE  = "__________";

cout << "Please enter a file name: ";

cin >> fileName;

inFile.open (fileName, ios::in);
while (!inFile)
{
    cout << fileName << " could not be opened, please enter new file name: ";
    cin >> fileName ;
    inFile.open (fileName, ios::in);
}

inFile.clear();               // reset read pointer to very beginning of file
    inFile.seekg(0L, ios::beg); 

    std::string word;
int count = 0;

while (inFile >> word)
{
 count++;
 if (count % 5 != 0)
      cout << word << endl;
}
}
```

And yes this a project I'm working on for my programming class.

Comment: Post the code you have so far.  We can then offer some clues to help you along.

Comment: The above program is working fine on my Linux machine without any change. Are you getting any runtime issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the number of words you've read and skip printing every 5th word, i.e. whenever the word count is a multiple of 5. For example:

```
std::string word;
int count = 0;

while (inFile >> word) {
  count++;
  if (count % 5 != 0)
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Comment: it's telling me no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Okay, so there's no build errors anymore, but now it won't print out my file at all.

Comment: Oops, I really meant `inFile >> word` where I had `cin >> word`. Corrected now.

Comment: Maybe you should update the code in your question so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried the exact code that you posted and it works fine for me. Are you sure you compiled and ran the latest version of your program?

Comment: It's printing out the message but each word is on a new line and it's not giving me the origional message.

Comment: Remove the `endl` so that it doesn't print each word on a new line. You probably want to actually replace the `endl` with a space.